# Delete the last character of a string using string manipulation in shell script

Tags: shell-script, string

I would like to delete the last character of a string, I tried this little script :

```
#! /bin/sh 

t="lkj"
t=${t:-2}
echo $t
```

but it prints "lkj", what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

In a POSIX shell, the syntax `${t:-2}` means something different - it expands to the value of `t` if `t` is set and non null, and otherwise to the value `2`. To trim a single character by parameter expansion, the syntax you probably want is `${t%?}`

Note that in `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`, `${t:(-2)}` or `${t: -2}` (note  the space) *are* legal as a substring expansion but are probably not what you want, since they return the substring starting at a position 2 characters in from the end (i.e. it removes the *first* character `i` of the string `ijk`).

See the Shell Parameter Expansion section of the Bash Reference Manual for more info:

- [Bash Reference Manual – Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Would you care to explain what is the magic behind '%?' ?

Comment: @afraisse `${parameter%word}` removes the shortest suffix pattern matching `word` - see the Parameter Expansion section of `man bash`

Comment: This works well for Bash 4.1.2:  ${t%?} for folks stuck with CentOS/RHEL 6.x

Answer (score 273):

With `bash` 4.2 and above, you can do:

```
${var::-1}
```

Example:

```
$ a=123
$ echo "${a::-1}"
12
```

Notice that for older `bash` ( for example, `bash 3.2.5` on OS X), you should leave spaces between and after colons:

```
${var: : -1}
```

Comment: This works for `bash` version 4.2-alpha and above, too bad the version I have access to is earlier. :-/

Comment: @iamaziz: From bash changelog, the negative length in `${var:offset:lenght}` was added only in `bash 4.2`. Maybe OSX add its own patch for `bash`.

Comment: @cuonglm perhaps. I am on El Capitan and it only works if I either leave spaces, or explicitly put the start and end e.g. `${v:2:-1}`.

Comment: @iamaziz: How about `${v::(-1)}` or `${v:: -1}`?

Comment: @cuonglm neither work :/

Comment: Doesn't work on mac.

Comment: @kuhaku yes, mac comes with bash 3.2 by default

Comment: Yeah well both of what you have in the answer don't work on mac: http://imgur.com/a/oeL9X

Comment: MACsters, look down to Russ's answer

Answer (score 112):

Using sed it should be as fast as

```
sed 's/.$//'
```

Your single **echo** is then `echo ljk | sed 's/.$//'`.
Using this, the 1-line string could be any size.

Comment: Note that in the general case, it doesn't _delete the last character of the string_, but the last character _of every line of the string_.

Comment: `sed -z 's/.$//` will do what you're looking for, working with multiple lines too.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I get `sed: illegal option -- z` on `macOS`

Comment: @TWiStErRob: that may remove the last newline...

Comment: Yes, `\n` is a character, @LuisA.Florit :) You can amend the regex easily if you know more about your input, for example `/.\n$/\n/` in your case to keep the last newline and remove the character before the last newline. I think even `/.\n?$/\n/` might be an option to ensure a new line at the end of stream.

Answer (score 86):

for removing the last `n` characters from a line that makes no use of `sed` OR `awk`:

```
> echo lkj | rev | cut -c (n+1)- | rev
```

so for example you can delete the last character `one character` using this:

```
> echo lkj | rev | cut -c 2- | rev

> lk
```

from `rev` manpage:

> DESCRIPTION
>        The rev utility copies the specified files to the standard output,
>        reversing the order of characters in every line.  If no files are speci-
>        fied, the standard input is read.

UPDATE:

if you don't know the length of the string, try:

```
$ x="lkj"
$ echo "${x%?}"
lk
```

Answer (score 66):

A few options depending on the shell:

- POSIX: `t=${t%?}`
- Bourne: `` t=`expr " $t" : ' \(.*\).'` ``
- zsh/yash: `t=${t[1,-2]}`
- bash/zsh: `t=${t:0:-1}`
- ksh93/bash/zsh/mksh: `t=${t:0:${#t}-1}`
- ksh93/bash/zsh/mksh: `t=${t/%?}`
- ksh93: `t=${t/~(E).$/}`
- es: `@ {t=$1} ~~ $t *?`

Note that while all are supposed to strip the last *character*, you'll find that some implementations (those that don't support multi-byte characters) strip the last *byte* instead (so would likely corrupt the last character if it was multi-byte).

The `expr` variant assumes `$t` doesn't end in more than one newline character. It will also return a non-zero exit status if the resulting string ends up being `0` (or `000` or even `-0` with some implementations). It could also give unexpected results if the string contains invalid characters.

Comment: Nice and thorough!  But... I assume all of those shells support POSIX, so everyone should just use that one to be the most portable.  Smallest character count, too!

Comment: @Russ, `t=${t%?}` is not Bourne but you're not likely to come across a Bourne shell nowadays. `${t%?}` does work in all the other ones though.

Comment: No fish shell option given! Probably more popular these days than ksh93...

Comment: @rien333. I'd wait for the interface to stabilize a bit. `fish` is work in progress. 2.3.0 which introduced the `string` builtin was not released at the time of the Q&A. With the version I'm testing it on, you need `string replace -r '(?s).\z' '' -- $t` (and I'd expect they'd want to change that, they should change the flags they pass to PCRE) or more convoluted ones. It also deals poorly with newline characters, and I know they're planning on changing that as well.

Comment: Upvoted for the POSIX answer. confirmed working on Bash 3.2.57(1)

Comment: Add fish shell example, not sure if fish has the more native string seeking/manipulation but `string trim` works for now.

Comment: @ElijahLynn, I've rejected the change as it does something different from the other examples. Removing the last character from a variable seems to be quite difficult with fish builtins if you want to allow the variable to contain newline characters. If you have a solution to remove the last character of `$t` in fish, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: Do not forget to start the script with `bash` and not `sh` to make it work and avoid `bad subst.`

Comment: @Timo, not sure what you mean. None of the solutions I gave are bash-specific. The only one invented by bash AFAIK is `t=${t:0:-1}` (extending the `${var:offset:length}` ksh93 operator). For each, I gave which shells support  it. You can use the Bourne/POSIX ones from and modern `sh`.

Comment: ok, Stephane, if you use a bash solution like the one with `var:offset:length` in a script you need to call your script with `bash`.

Answer (score 54):

The most portable, and shortest, answer is almost certainly:

`${t%?}`

This works in bash, sh, ash, dash, busybox/ash, zsh, ksh, etc.

It works by using old-school shell parameter expansion. Specifically, the `%` specifies to remove the smallest matching suffix of parameter `t` that matches the glob pattern `?` (ie: any character).

See "Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern" [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) for a (much) more detailed explanation and more background. Also see the docs for your shell (eg: `man bash`) under "parameter expansion".

---

As a side note, if you wanted to remove the *first* character instead, you would use `${t#?}`, since `#` matches from the front of the string (prefix) instead of the back (suffix).

Also worth noting is that both `%` and `#` have `%%` and `##` versions, which match the *longest* version of the given pattern instead of the shortest.  Both `${t%%?}` and `${t##?}` would do the same as their single operator in this case, though (so don't add the useless extra character). This is because the given `?` pattern only matches a single character. Mix in a `*` with some non-wildcards and things get more interesting with `%%` and `##`.

Understanding parameter expansions, or at least knowing about their existence and knowing how to look them up, is incredibly useful for writing and deciphering shell scripts of many flavors.  Parameter expansions often look like arcane shell voodoo to many people because... well... they *are* arcane shell voodoo (although pretty well documented if you know to look for "parameter expansion").  Definitely good to have in the tool belt when you're stuck in a shell, though.

Comment: Short and sweet, and works on both MacOS and Linux!

Answer (score 19):

```
t=lkj
echo ${t:0:${#t}-1}
```

You get a substring from 0 to the string length -1. Note however that this substraction is  bash specific, and won't work on other shells.

For instance, `dash` isn't able to parse even

```
echo ${t:0:$(expr ${#t} - 1)}
```

For example, on Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is `dash`

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `head` to print out all but the last character.

```
$ s='i am a string'
$ news=$(echo -n $s | head -c -1)
$ echo $news
i am a strin
```

But unfortunately some versions of `head` do not include the leading `-` option. This is the case for the `head` that comes with OS X.

Answer (score 7):

Some refinements. To remove more than one character, you can add multiple question marks. For example, to remove the last two characters from the variable: `$SRC_IP_MSG`, you can use:

```
SRC_IP_MSG=${SRC_IP_MSG%??}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is easy enough to do using regular expression:

```
n=2
echo "lkj" | sed "s/\(.*\).\{$n\}/\1/"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete some possible usages of pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Testing substring removal
STR="Exemple string with trailing whitespace "
echo "'$STR'"
echo "Removed trailing whitespace: '${STR:0:${#STR}-1}'"
echo "Removed trailing whitespace: '${STR/%\ /}'"
```

The first syntax takes a substring from a string, the syntax is 
**`${STRING:OFFSET:LENGTH}`** 
For the second one, do notice the **`%`** sign, which means 'from end of line' and the syntax is 
 **`${STRING/PATTERN/SUBSTITUTION}`**

And here are two shorter forms of the above mentioned

```
echo "Removed trailing whitespace: '${STR::-1}'"
echo "Removed trailing whitespace: '${STR%\ }'"
```

Here notice again the **`%`** sign, meaning 'Remove ( that is, replace with '' ) the *shortest* matched pattern (here represented by escaped space **'\ '** from the end of the *PARAMETER* - here named *STR*

Answer (score 1):

As we can also use **php** in command line, or shell scripts.
It is sometimes useful for surgical parsing.

```
php -r "echo substr('Hello', 0, -1);" 
// Output hell
```

With piping:

```
echo "hello" | php -r "echo substr(trim(fgets(STDIN)), 0, -1);"
// Output hell
```

Answer (score 0):

In ksh:

```
echo ${ORACLE_SID/%?/}
```