# Delete last characters of strings in a txt file

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file called `TempsModel.txt` which is created as follows:

```
ls /media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/* > TempsModel.txt
```

so it lists all the files in that directory. These files are all compressed netcdf files so it looks like this:

```
/media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/20091201_000000.nc.gz
/media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/20091201_002023.nc.gz
/media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/20091201_003009.nc.gz
/media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/20091201_004020.nc.gz
```

I need this list to not contain the `.gz`. How do I remove these three characters?
I tried question [Delete the last character of a string using string manipulation in shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/delete-the-last-character-of-a-string-using-string-manipulation-in-shell-script) and [Remove last character from line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83038/remove-last-character-from-line)

But how do I create a second file `TempsModel2.txt` where the list does not contain these last three characters?

Comment: You could do it in one operation, e.g. `ls /media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/* | sed  's/.gz$//'  > TempsModel.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not best practice to create that file using `ls` but given the sample input you have provided you can use

## `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/.gz$/, ""); print}' TempsModel.txt > TempsModel2.txt
```

## `sed`:

```
sed 's/.gz$//' TempsModel.txt > TempsModel2.txt
```

---

In order to create the initial file without ever having the .gz extension you could do:

```
for file in /media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/*; do echo "${file%.gz}"; done > TempsModel.txt
```

You could also do:

```
set -- /media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/*
printf '%s\n' "${@%.gz}" > TempsModel.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If zsh is available, then similar to this [Using parameter expansion to generate arguments list for `mkdir -p`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315647/65304), you could use a glob qualifier to do the suffix removal on the fly:

```
setopt histsubstpattern extendedglob

print -rl -- /media/Elise/2811226E69F71131/ModelOutput/*.gz(#q:s/%.gz/) > TempsModel2.txt
```